# HTML - Add certain spaces. so each row is equal vertically

Tags: html, space, vertical-text

I'm not quite sure how to explain it completely, but i'm trying. I'm in the process of making a list of some books and possibly have some categories, but I want the lines and words to stand even, like on the same spot.

Here's my code:

```
Number&emsp; Name&emsp; Author&emsp;    Release<br>
1&emsp;     Jacob's Book&emsp;  Jacob&emsp; 2021<br>
2&emsp;     Anne-Marianne' Cooking Book&emsp;   Anne-Marianne&emsp; 2021<br>
3&emsp;     Ole's Car Book&emsp;    Ole&emsp;   2021<br>
4&emsp;     Frederikke's Kitchen Book&emsp; Frederikke&emsp;    2021<br>
```

How it looks like:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJCkj.png)

What I want it to look like (so each row is exactly equal vertically.):
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC93K.png)
(Edited that through an editor).

Comment: Use HTML tables to achieve the effect.
Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_align

Try with table & text-alight